# Symfony2 - Set minimum number of embedded forms

Tags: symfony

Using the scenario in [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), I would like to ensure that a `Task` always have at least 1 `Tag`. For my case however, the relationship of `Task` and `Tag` is `1:n` rather than `n:m`.

I am particularly concerned on the scenario where all `Tags` are removed (I'd like to prevent this). How can I ensure that a `Task` form always have at least 1 `Tag`?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. For what do you need a minimum number of forms? You should explain it much more.

Comment: Hi @Stony, thanks for pointing that out. I basically have an entity that must have at least one other dependent entity. I wanted to avoid being too specific with my question but I hope the question is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [m0c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12247266/1349295) the solution was indeed to utilize a custom validation constraint. However, I found out that such a constraint validator already exists in Symfony2.1 so I took the liberty of porting it for 2.0 (since some interfaces apparently changed in 2.1).

Here are ported versions (for 2.0) of [Bernhard Schussek's](https://github.com/bschussek) `Count.php` and `CountValidator.php` for counting collections (see https://github.com/symfony/Validator/tree/master/Constraints).

### Count.php

```
namespace MyVendor\MyBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\MissingOptionsException;

/**
 * @Annotation
 *
 * @api
 */
class Count extends Constraint
{
    public $minMessage = 'This collection should contain {{ limit }} elements or more.';
    public $maxMessage = 'This collection should contain {{ limit }} elements or less.';
    public $exactMessage = 'This collection should contain exactly {{ limit }} elements.';
    public $min;
    public $max;

    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        if (null !== $options && !is_array($options)) {
            $options = array(
                'min' => $options,
                'max' => $options,
            );
        }

        parent::__construct($options);

        if (null === $this->min && null === $this->max) {
            throw new MissingOptionsException('Either option "min" or "max" must be given for constraint ' . __CLASS__, array('min', 'max'));
        }
    }
}
```

### CountValidator.php

```
namespace MyVendor\MyBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

class CountValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!is_array($value) && !$value instanceof \Countable) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'array or \Countable');
        }

        $count = count($value);

        if ($constraint->min == $constraint->max
                && $count != $constraint->min) {
            $this->setMessage($constraint->exactMessage, array(
                '{{ count }}' => $count,
                '{{ limit }}' => $constraint->min,
            ));

            return false;
        }

        if (null !== $constraint->max && $count > $constraint->max) {
            $this->setMessage($constraint->maxMessage, array(
                '{{ count }}' => $count,
                '{{ limit }}' => $constraint->min,
            ));

            return false;
        }

        if (null !== $constraint->min && $count < $constraint->min) {
            $this->setMessage($constraint->minMessage, array(
                '{{ count }}' => $count,
                '{{ limit }}' => $constraint->min,
            ));

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom Validator which checks if the property where the relationshop is mapped to on entity level has some elements in the collection.

And the Validator fails:

```
   public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (count($value) <1 ) {
            //also define a message for your custom validator
            $this->setMessage($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

For instructions how to implement this custom validator: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: Thanks @m0c, I'll check this out. A concrete example of how this would apply to the Task-Tag example in [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) would be better though as it would help future references to questions similar to this. And would be more convenient for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

do u want to just validate upon posting, wheter or not there is atleast 1 tag,

or do u want the form to actually already have 1 empty tag in it upon loading ?
(wich i assume bacause u say *"how can I ensure that a Task **form** always have at least 1 Tag?"*)

if u need the second, just

```
$tag1 = new Tag();
$tag1->name = 'tag1';
$task->getTags()->add($tag1);
```

Before

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);
```

like the docs say..

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your help I just realized how misleading my question is. I have, however, already done what you suggested. What I need is validation as m0c have brought up. Still, I appreciate the effort.